# Basic Inventory System Using Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a basic (very, very basic) inventory system in Unity though C#, and am having trouble deciding how to use arrays. Would it be best to have a different multidimensional array for each inventory slot, with each dimension carrying the integer values of item data? Or use a jagged array , with each "jag" representing a different value of item data? Or is there a better solution that doesn't use arrays? I plan to have around 40-50 inventory slots, and each item having around 10-15 aspects, so neither option seems simple. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create a simple object that holds the item aspects (this object would represent a single inventory slot) and just have an array of those objects. Take a look at the [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, it may be easier than using an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more you divide up the objects are the better. You should normalize the objects as much as possible, being said separate a chair object to multiple parts and have chair inherit / instantiate some generalized properties. I believe the following would explain better;

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Properties Props { get; set; }
}

class Properties
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    // All of the possible properties here...

}
```

The Item has a field called Props which is global for a lot of objects / items in your game, and Item is an object that can refer to many things. If you construct your objects like this, you can use them over and over again instead of creating separate objects for each feature in your game.

Then you can finally create the inventory as the following;

```
var Inventory = new List < Item > {
    new Item {
        Name = "Bullet", Quantity = 100, Props = new Properties {
            Height = 10, Weight = 10
        }
    }
};
```

**Edit:**

Upon your request, I will try to explain the code a bit more. Lists are generic classes that holds data for you. You could create an array as well but Lists are more dynamic, and you may eventually have sizing issues with Arrays more than with lists. Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more information on Lists.

I believe the second part is the one you may be having a tough time with. The following pseudo code should explain it better.

```
Class Item { Fields, Properties }
Class Properties { Fields }

new Inventory = List of <Items> ( New Item Class(es))
```

As you see above, we create List of Items and the Inventory type would be List as well since it would host items.

I hope it makes better sense now.

Comment: Is that C#? It looks a lot like JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I thank you for the help, But It would be great if you could explain this code a bit more. I have little experience with lists/arrays, and do not know the operators, commands, etc.

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Although what is the difference between Class Item and Class Properties?

Comment: It is just the fields. They both are classes with different fields. For example, you could use properties for something other than item if you generalize it well enough. The further you divide up the classes, the more use you can make of them. In this example, you could use Item for a lot of things in your game, as well as properties.

Comment: So those would be like folders to organise and contain different kinds of info, and I can re-name them whatever I want(like make Class Item into Class Pickup)?

Comment: Pickup would be a method and you would pass an instantiation of the Class Item. Just like public void PickupItem(Item DroppedFromSomewhere) { Inventory.Add(DroppedFromSomewhere) }.

Comment: You can put it right under the namespace. Here is a quick tutorial : https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/classes